In Deep Learning Image Segmentation : Is it better to train N models for N classes vs. One model of N classes
I was wondering if you have any recent publication references or any experience about the "Is it better to train N models for N classes vs. One model of N classes" issue in Deep Learning Image Segmentation ?
I known that it depends of backbone, type of data, etc... But I can't find anything recent, reliable and robust (paper types) about this question (all objects confounded).
Thanks a lot
